# Getting html from site c#

Tags: c#, html

I need to parse some data from this page https://warcraft3.info/replays/18723

Only WebBrowser helps me to get more html part, but I can't get all html text still. But WebBrowser control shows page correctly.
When I save page using browser I get what I need.
Can anybody help me with some advice?

```
 var d = (wfhSample.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).Document.Body.OuterHtml;
```

Comment: Have you tried [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)

Comment: @Peter Smith, it works! thank you! finally got it!

Answer (score 0):

First port of call is to read the following, you can extract pretty much anything that has valid markup. https://jsoup.org/

Comment: This is a Java library; does it have a C# equivalent?

Comment: from NuGet doesnt work too because of no mono.android referense

Comment: iText7, its a C# implementation of the above

Comment: https://github.com/matarillo/dcsoup, dcsoup: C# port of jsoup HTML Parser http://jsoup.org/

Comment: @kingtreelo, but... I get this error The type 'IJavaObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly Mono.Android. And I cant get Mono.Android for my winform project

Answer (score 0):

[HTML Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/)

> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).

I've personally used this for different projects. It's easy and friendly to use.